# Cascade Flux results

Tags: java, spring-boot, mono, spring-webflux, flux

I have two actions in Mono, both returning similar object -
Mono action1()
Mono action2()

I tried doing -
Flux1.blockFirst();
Flux2.blockFirst();

both of the flux are performing the action I want. But one of the requirement is if any action fails then both flux should fail or call action to revert the previous action.

Comment: do you want to execute actions in parallel or sequentially and what is `Flux1` / `Flux2`?

Comment: sequential works

Comment: I want both of the actions to fail as the one of the actions fail

Comment: Flux1 and Flux2 are two flux publishers that I have created. I think their would be a good way to do it - but just wanted get opinion if what is a good way to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `Flux.zip(flux1, flux2)....` is what you're looking for:

```
public static <T1,T2> Flux<Tuple2<T1,T2>> zip(Publisher<? extends T1> source1,
                                              Publisher<? extends T2> source2)
```

> Zip two sources together, that is to say wait for all the sources to
> emit one element and combine these elements once into a Tuple2. The
> operator will continue doing so until any of the sources completes.
> Errors will immediately be forwarded. This "Step-Merge" processing is
> especially useful in Scatter-Gather scenarios.

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#zip-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-

There are various overloads with different number of publishers to combine and possible specification of a combinator function.

Also, some other ways to combine publishers are described here: https://www.baeldung.com/reactor-combine-streams